NullInjectorError: No provider for CookieService! Angular 17+
With the new Dependency injection and standalone applications its a bit unclear to me how I provide a custom library at root.
I tried to install ngx-cookie but I want to use it at service level, which has no import.
 NullInjectorError: No provider for CookieService!
With httpClient, there is a provideHttpClient() but how to provide a custom library in app.config.ts
bootstrapApplication looks at this file

We can use importProvidersFrom to add providers from modules in the providers array of bootstrapApplication.
bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideHttpClient(),
    importProvidersFrom(CookieModule.withOptions()),
    // importProvidersFrom(CookieModule), // <- also try if this if above does not work!
  ],
});

